# How can Haskell code utilise brackets to separate or tidy up information while using list comprehensions?

Tags: haskell, brackets

I am trying to write a function where the expression:

```
crosswordFind letter inPosition len words
```

should return all the items from `words` which

- (i) are of the given length `len` and
- (ii) have `letter` in the position `inPosition`.

For example, seven-letter words that have `’k’` in position `1`, the expression:

```
crosswordFind ’k’ 1 7 ["funky", "fabulous", "kite", "icky", "ukelele"]
```

will return

```
["ukelele"]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
crosswordFind :: Char -> Int -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
crosswordFind letter pos len words = 
    if isAlpha **words** == letter && 
        **words** !! letter == pos && 
        length **pos** == len 
    then words 
    else []
```

The code above is after altering to remove the brackets that I placed to separate each condition. The code below is the original one (which is wrong):

```
crosswordFind :: Char -> Int -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
crosswordFind letter pos len words =
   [ if [isAlpha x == letter] && 
        [xs !! n == pos] && 
        [length x == len] 
     then words 
     else [] ]
```

I understand why it is wrong (because a list of length 1 will be returned), but why can't brackets like these be used to section off code in Haskell?

How can this question be solved using list comprehensions? And I'm wondering what to put in to replace the bolded words as well to make the code run normally.

Comment: *formatting,* please. please add backticks around code identifiers in the text of the question.

Comment: I think [filter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) is the function you're looking for here.

Comment: Start by writing a function of type `Char -> Int -> Int -> String -> Bool` that can determine if a *single* word matches. Then use that function with `filter`.

Comment: If you just want to group expressions for precedence, or readability, you need to use `(...)` rather than `[...]`. But lots of nested parentheses aren't very idiomatic in Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` with a condition that should satisfy two criteria:

1. the word has the given length; and
2. the character on position `pos` is the given `letter`.

For a word `w` of the `words` we thus check if `length w == len` and `w !! pos == letter`.

We thus can implement this with:

```
crosswordFind :: Eq a => a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
crosswordFind letter pos len words = filter (\w -> length w == len && w !! pos == letter) words
```

we can also omit the `words` variable and work with:

```
crosswordFind :: Eq a => a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
crosswordFind letter pos len = filter (\w -> length w == len && w !! pos == letter)
```

The above is not very safe: if the `pos` is greater than or equal to the length, then `w !! pos == letter` will raise an error. Furthermore for infinite strings (lists of `Char`s), `length` will loop forever. I leave it as an exercise to introduce safer variants. You can determine these with recursive functions.

Comment: Ahh, so is it better if I convert the above code into a list comprehension and install an additional guard that caps the pos to be equal to the length? Or can that be done in the filter code itself?

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode: filter will only retain items that satisfy the condition (the lambda expression in this case). You can use list comprehension as well, then it is `[w | w <- words, length w == len && w !! pos == letter]`

Comment: yep, I've ran into the same conclusion right just now. Thank you! So if I want to add a condition that caps the pos, where and how will one do it?

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are part of *list syntax*. Nothing else.

*Lists.*

You can freely utilize *round* parentheses `( )` for the grouping of expressions.

Some expression types, like `let` and `do`, have their own separators `{`, `;`, `}`, which can also be used, especially to prevent whitespace brittleness.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, so the round parentheses are just to group expressions together and are not used in functions, right? Btw, what does the "brittleness" of whitespace mean?

Comment: it is _code_ brittleness, caused by whitespace misuse. without the explicit separators, you have to keep indentation strictly right, in `let` and `do` blocks. if you indent your lines wrongly it can cause errors. if you have some tabs instead of spaces, and this causes different indentation than it seems (editor: tab=4 spaces, haskell: tab=8 spaces), such errors can be hard to find. with the explicit separators wrong indentation won't cause errors.